# Set minimum or maximum date to Datepicker but this code do nothing

Tags: android

I want to show minimum date as current date and max as +7 days from current date.

But this code do nothing for me. I click on `Textbox` to open `Datepicker` for selection the date.

```
    datebox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            mdatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mdatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                    Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    mcurrentDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
                    mdatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(mcurrentDate.getTimeInMillis());
                    date = String.valueOf(year) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)
                            + "-" + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                    datebox.setText(date);
                }
            }, yy, mm, dd);
            mdatePicker.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, to restrict min and max date.

```
mdatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        String date = String.valueOf(year) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)
                                + "-" + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                        Log.v("Date", "Date==" + date);
                    }
                }, yy, mm, dd);
                mdatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                mcurrentDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
                mdatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(mcurrentDate.getTimeInMillis());
                mdatePicker.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

set this code outside onDateSet method before `mdatePicker.show()`

```
mdatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                    Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    mcurrentDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
                    mdatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(mcurrentDate.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I implement a date picker , this one restricts ages under 18 to pick.

```
profileDateOfbirth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DatePickerDialog d= new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
            c.add(Calendar.YEAR,-18);

            d.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());

            d.show();
        }
    });


 final  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel();
        }

    };

 private void updateLabel() {
        String myFormat = "yy-MM-dd"; //In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

        profileDateOfbirth.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime())); 
}
```